# Using Android Emulator's Root Shell via Command Line

Tags: shell, android-emulator

I want to get a root shell since my adbd crashes. But the `-shell` option does not work. Meanwhile, I found out, that you can get a shell by using `-show-kernel`. But I would like to communicate with the root shell by TCP. There's also an open issue at google: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202760

When starting an Android emulator (SDK 24.4.1) on Linux by command line, you should be able to get a root shell by using the `-shell` command-line option. At least that's what [the manual](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#advanced) says

> Create a root shell console on the current terminal. You can use this command even if the adb daemon in the emulated system is broken. Pressing Ctrl-C from the shell stops the emulator, instead of the shell

But when starting the emulator like

```
emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd nougat-x86_64 -gpu off -no-window -shell
```

I do see the shell output of the Android emulator booting, but I cannot send any commands to it, i.e. `ls`.

Also, opening a TCP port for the shell and communicating via telnet shows the same behavior.

```
emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd nougat-x86_64 -gpu off -no-window -shell-serial tcp::4444,server,nowait
telnet localhost 4444
```

There's not much information about this topic on the internet, but perhaps someone already dealt with this topic.

Comment: This seems to have also been the topic at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374975/android-emulator-shell-redirection

Comment: Use `adb shell` of course.  If I recall an emulator would typically give you that shell as root by default.  If not, for a configuration which supports offering a root shell, do `adb root` first (rather obviously, that is not something that works on a consumer *device* configured in the way that Android was designed for consumer devices to be configured)

Answer (score 0):

From [Android source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/master/android/main.c) line 698, seems the `-shell` option is as same as `-logcat` option, thus I think the documentation is not described well and of course the `-shell` option won't bring you an interactive root shell from the virtual serial. Maybe I'm wrong, I only tested this on macOS.

With a further test, as same as [this guy's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374975/android-emulator-shell-redirection), the `-show-kernel` will actually get you the kernel log and an interactive rootable console.